# Is there a difference between setting Session.Timeout or adding it to the web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In ASP.NET there are two ways of setting the session timeout.

**In the code:**

[`Session.Timeout = 20`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(v=vs.90).aspx)

**or In web.config**

[`<sessionState timeout="20"/>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx)

But what I don't understand is the difference between the two forms.

Are there any?

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) they are pretty much the same.

Comment: The only difference I can note easily is that the first is only set when the code is executed, and the web.config one is always set in the server.

Comment: That's how it's intended to work.

Comment: difference is if you put the session timeout value in `web.config` file then it will be easy for you if in any case you ask to increase the session timeout time, else you need to re-deploy whole project if you need to change it in a code.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The value in web.config is a (default) timeout value for all sessions. In code you are able to give specific sessions a different timeout.

Comment: I see, so you could make different session times for a specific user in your application, for example. Correct?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - yes, that is what I meant.